# Read and process files in scala

Tags: scala, apache-commons, java-io

How do I read contents of all files present in a file with a 7z extension. 
Let's say I have abc.7z with part1.csv and part2.csv and xyz.7z with part3.csv and part4.csv.

I want to read contents of part1.csv and part2.csv which are in abc.7z and also part3.csv and part4.csv which are in xyz.7z.

I have tried but somehow unable to do it correctly **in scala**, appreciate any help!

Comment: Is it feasible to just extract the 7z file using Apache Commons Compress and read files later using scala ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach how you could do it. It misses a lot of error handling and edge cases but show how this can be done.

Basically you will need to add following dependencies to your sbt:

```
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-compress" % "1.16.1",
  "org.tukaani" % "xz" % "1.8"
```

I just used very simple files:

**part1.cv**

```
name, value
part1, 1
```

**part2.cv**

```
name, value
part2, 2
```

**part3.cv**

```
name, value
part3, 3
```

**part4.cv**

```
name, value
part4, 4
```

And then distributed them into `abc.7z` and `xyz.7z` files as you described

Here is a very simple code:

```
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object CompressionTest extends App {

  def loadCsvLinesFromZFile(compressedFile: String, fileName: String): Vector[String] = {
    val zFile = new SevenZFile(new File(compressedFile))

    zFile.getEntries.asScala.find { entry ⇒
      // internally zFile keeps last file with call to getNextEntry
      // it's a bit ugly in scala terms
      zFile.getNextEntry
      !entry.isDirectory && entry.getName == fileName
    }.fold(Vector.empty[String]){ csv ⇒
      val content = new Array[Byte](csv.getSize.toInt)
      zFile.read(content, 0, content.length)
      new String(content).split("\n").toVector
    }
  }

  val allOutput = (loadCsvLinesFromZFile("abc.7z", "part1.csv") ++
  loadCsvLinesFromZFile("abc.7z", "part2.csv") ++
  loadCsvLinesFromZFile("xyz.7z", "part3.csv") ++
  loadCsvLinesFromZFile("xyz.7z", "part4.csv")).mkString("\n")

  println(allOutput)
}
```

And this gives me the following output:

```
name, value
part1, 1
name, value
part2, 2
name, value
part3, 3
name, value
part4, 4
```

I hope this helps, at least to get you started.