# Scala: Reading a huge zipped text file line by line without loading into memory

Tags: scala, io, compression

I have a text file of size 100-200 GB. So I wish to store in a compressed format (such as zip). However, I need to process it one line at a time due to its size. Though it is straightforward to read a text file one line at a time with `io.Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines`, but that is only for unzipped files.

Is there some efficient way to read a compressed file in scala line-by-line? I couldn't find any examples but a closer implementation I saw was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594756/read-and-process-files-in-scala) but it loads file into memory. Unlike examples that are generally given that work with zip archive, I need to process only one text file that is compressed. I would be grateful for any pointers or leads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file is Gzipped, java's `GzipInputStream` gives you streaming access:

```
   val lines: Iterator[String] = Source
     .fromInputStream(new GzipInputStream(new FileInputStream("foo.gz")))
     .getLines
```

If it is a *zip archive* as your question suggests, that's more complicated. Zip archives are more like folders than individual files. You'd have to read the table of content first, and then scan through the entries to find one you want to read (or to read all of them). Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67372455/why-source-frominputstream-is-working-with-gzipinputstream-but-not-with-zipinput/67372740#67372740)

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very helpful. I had to just change the case to `GZIPInputStream` to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Consider [better-files](https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files#zip-apis) which gives an `Iterator` into the compressed file

```
import better.files._
File("foo.gz").newInputStream.asGzipInputStream().lines
// : Iterator[String]
```

so you could process the file line by line without loading it whole into memory.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Dima's suggestion was with in-built library so it was a little easier to use, but I was not aware of better-files which is very versatile and powerful. Learnt something very useful.